# How to test DAL implemented using linq2sql and Repository pattern?

Tags: unit-testing, linq-to-sql, repository

Here is a part of my DAL.

DataContext interface:

```
public interface IDataContextFactory
{
    System.Data.Linq.DataContext Context { get; }
    void SaveAll();
}
```

Here is my data context class which contains generated classes:

```
partial class InternetRailwayTicketSalesDataContext: DataContext, IDataContextFactory
{
    public System.Data.Linq.DataContext Context
    {
        get { return this; }
    }

    public void SaveAll()
    {
        this.SubmitChanges();
    } 
}
```

Here is my Repository interface:

```
public interface IRepository<T> where T : class
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Return all instances of type T.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    IEnumerable<T> GetAll();
}
```

Here is my Repository interface implementation:

```
public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
{
    protected IDataContextFactory _dataContextFactory;

    /// <summary>
    /// Return all instances of type T.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public IEnumerable<T> GetAll()
    {
        return GetTable;
    }

    private System.Data.Linq.Table<T> GetTable
    {
        get { return _dataContextFactory.Context.GetTable<T>(); }
    }
}
```

Here is an interface for concrete repository class:

```
interface IPasswayRepository
{ 
    bool IsPasswayExists(int id);
}
```

And finally here is a concrete repository class implementation:

```
class PasswayRepository:Repository<Passway>, IPasswayRepository
{
    public PasswayRepository(IDataContextFactory context)
        : base(context)    
    {                    
    }

    public bool IsPasswayExists(int id)
    {
        if (GetAll().Where(pass => pass.Id == id && pass.IsDeleted == false).Count() > 0)
            return true;
        else
            return false;           
    }   
}
```

Can you give me an example of how to test IsPasswayExists method? (you can use any mock framework if you want to).

Comment: testing *what*? What do you mean by testing your dal? Code to test *that method* would create a 'Passway', check its id, then call that methid with that id and an invalid one and verify correct return values, then remove the added 'Passway'. Incidenrally, your IsPasswayExists can be written much simpler:

Comment: return GetAll().Any(pass=> pass.id == id && !pass.IsDeleted);

Comment: But how to break the dependence on a database?

Comment: Well, that would be the point of dependency injection. A tutorial on that is far beyond the scope of an answer here. You could inject your mock in place of your Context, inside your Repository.